# API call is giving outdated response in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsurlrequest

I am making a HTTP get request in swift where I am getting an outdated response for some reason..I have compared the response in Postman with the one I printed in the Xcode and I'm getting this..

Response Headers in Postman:

[image: Postman response headers screenshot]

Response Headers printed in Xcode Console:

[image: Xcode console response headers screenshot]

see the sections highlighted in green, both the calls are made at the same time. This is a live API of my project and as there is no change in the current live data I am not showing JSON response. But as you can see in the response headers, the value for field "Date" in both Postman and Xcode is different.. When I do it in Postman, it is giving me new response every time. But in Xcode I'm getting the same response all day. I don't know why This is happening. And after erasing the contents of simulator (or deleting the app from simulator) and reinstalling the project again it gave me a new updated response. But it's again repeated...

Code in RequestManager Class:

```
import Foundation

class RequestManager {

class func callTheGetAPI(urlString: String, closure: @escaping (Data?)->Void) {

    let url = URL.init(string: urlString)
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in

        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            print(httpResponse!.allHeaderFields)
            closure(data)
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
  }
}
```

code in my ViewController:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getRecommendedData()
}

func getRecommendedData() {
    let url = APIManager.API_01
    RequestManager.callTheGetAPI(urlString: url, closure: { response in

        do {
            if (try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [[String : Any]]) != nil{
//             print(json)
            }
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

    })
}
```

This is all I have guys.. If anyone knows what's happening or if I'm doing something wrong.. Please help..

Comment: Did you try with `URLRequest` and request type to `reloadIgnoringCacheData`?

Comment: @TheTiger No. but, How to do that?

Comment: Check all the init methods of `URLRequest `.

Comment: @TheTiger I just did it and it worked OMG..! Thank you so much my friend..

Comment: Great! Would you mind to accept it as answer ? ;)

Comment: @TheTiger But, I wonder why it happened..? it never happened to me before....

Comment: @TheTiger Sure thing, give it as an answer.. It surely would help someone..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace below line

```
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
```

With

```
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60)
```

From the documentation **reloadIgnoringCacheData: Specifies that the
        data for the URL load should be loaded from the origin source. No
        existing local cache data, regardless of its freshness or validity,
        should be used to satisfy a URL load request.**

By default it uses caches.